echo. is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet
I am observing an odd behaviour in PowerShell. I can echo hi but I can't echo. to get a newline:

It does work in Command Prompt:

One answer suggests that the .ps1 file might have a BOM in it. I tried converting my script to ANSI but this did not help, and as you can see from the above it still fails even without a script file.
Another answer suggests that there might be a file named echo. in the same directory, but there isn't.
How can I fix echo. or otherwise how can I echo a newline please?
Running just echo without the . halts and prompts for input.
Running write hi works but write. fails, in the same way as echo. The same goes for Write-Output and Write-Host.
I have tried manually installing the latest version of PowerShell (v7.4.1) but this did not help.

Do not add images when plain text will do.

@Bib It is clearer this way - I don't fancy typing out font colours in HTML...

No it is not. The colours are not required.

@Bib I didn't say they're required. It's not clearer? So Microsoft are wrong? Perhaps you should apply for a job with them and correct everything else you disagree with.

@DannyBeckett How about you stop being lazy and format your question in an appropriate way?

@paladin Lol what? It's not lazy, it's clearer. You may not find any value in the colours but I do. You both have about 1k to 5k rep, I have about 50k rep. The pair of you are making demands - believe it or not being polite & the word "please" go a long way! My question is by no means inappropriate. Is this the new generation of grammar nazis?

echo. is a backward compatibility behavior for cmd.exe shell scripts (batch files). Other trailing characters also work besides . (try : or /). PowerShell has no such constraint, as PowerShell doesn't directly execute cmd.exe shell scripts.

After much searching I've just found a working solution.
This doesn't work:
echo "\n"

But this does:
echo "`n"

I am guessing that echo. is only implemented in cmd, not ps.

You guess correctly. As noted in my comment to your question, this is a backward compatibility behavior for cmd.exe that goes all the way back to MS-DOS batch files. Since PowerShell doesn't execute batch files (cmd.exe shell scripts) directly, there's no need to mimic this behavior.

You could also use a function, if you like, like so: function echo. { echo "" }, after that you can use the "command" echo..

Nice idea! Worth noting that the output differs between echo ""  and echo "\n"`

echo. usually only produces 1 newline, and not 2 newlines. The reason why you see 2 newlines when using echo. is because you are using echo on.

Makes sense, thanks!
